# How to convert to a Bulk Insert

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Given the following data, how would I do a `BulkInsert` in django?

```
list_of_data = [
    {'name': 'Paul'}, 
    {'name': 'Robert'
]

# with a normal insert
for data in list_of_data:
    Person.objects.create(name=data['name'])
```

Comment: I don't think it is difficult to take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) for bulk insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in
>   an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many
>   objects there are)

```
Person.objects.bulk_create([Person(**data) for data in list_of_data])
```